# Theme Install using a Custom Repository

Tags: plugin-development, themes

The standard WP Themes Install is available in Appearance --> Theme Install nav-tab.
There is a way to add a new nav-tab and browsing into a Custom Themes Repository?
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

The existing system is set up as a 2-part integration between your individual blog and the API at WordPress.org.  You enter a search term, and your blog retrieves information from WordPress.org.  Then you can download themes from the same location.  That kind of integration doesn't exist anywhere else because, well, no one's bothered to build it.

So even if you could add a tab that pointed somewhere else, *you need a* ***somewhere else*** *to point it in the first place.*

There's [been discussion](http://konstruktors.com/blog/wordpress/2538-automatic-updates-for-plugins-and-themes-hosted-outside-wordpress-extend/) on [the WP Hackers list](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2011-January/037347.html) and [even on this site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/plugin-and-theme-repository-configuration-who-wants-to-help) regarding standardizing an API for hosting your own repositories ... but if anyone's started, their efforts are still in the very early stages.

While there's not currently a way to add a new tab and browsing to a custom repository (mostly because there *aren't* custom repositories), anything is possible.

Comment: I haven't delved into it too deeply, but the folks at iThemes have done something along this line. It's a fairly straightforward store of plugin/theme name + version number. They use this to query a REST interface on one of their servers to see what the most current revs are and then download as necessary.